# How to embed an XUL Application in SWT Browser?

Tags: java, swt, xul, xulrunner

I want to host my XUL application inside another Java application that uses SWT.

I know that it is possible to embed the browser windows using SWT.MIZILLA as a flag.

But how do I host my XUL application inside that browser window?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to load your XUL file using [Browser.setUrl()](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/Browser.html#setUrl(java.lang.String)) method. If you are on Linux, no need to specify SWT.MOZILLA (as embedded Firefox is also capable of loading XUL). Be careful when using SWT 3.7 (its M1 is just released), as it uses WebKitGtk+ as the default browser on Linux.